# Truth table to prove statements

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

A, B and C. When questioned A says ''If B did not do it, then it was C." B says ''A and C did it together or C did it alone". C says ''We all did it together."

How would i be able to put these into an equation to use in truth table?

Any help at all would be great :)

Comment: Are we to assume $\;A,B,C\;$ always all speak the truth? lie? something else? What is your goal?  What have you tried already?

Comment: @MarnixKlooster The goals are to find who's lying and who's telling the truth. but i have no idea what equations would be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ denote "A did it."

Let $B$ denote "B did it."

Let $C$ denote "C did it."

A's claim: $\lnot B \rightarrow C$.

B's claim: $(A \land C) \lor C$

C's claim: $A \land B \land C$.

Can you see that we can make the case that two are telling the truth, and the third is telling a lie. Whose the sole liar?

Comment: Ahh, that's what i needed. Cheers for the starting help @amWhy

Comment: @amWhy: Such nice feedback +1